# How to retrieve access token with spring security and auth0?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I am absolutely new to java Spring Boot and security in general. I am trying to learn to build an Spring Boot application which is supposed to call an API along with the access token that is received during the authentication process with the auth0-service. I have been following this tutorial https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-security-mvc to implement the authentication, and everything is working fine. For example I can read the accesstoken in plain text by printing it to the console like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected void getCallback(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try {
      Tokens tokens = controller.handle(req, res);
      System.out.println(tokens.getAccessToken());
      TokenAuthentication tokenAuth = new TokenAuthentication(JWT.decode(tokens.getIdToken()));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenAuth);
      res.sendRedirect(redirectOnSuccess);
 }
```

I think that the call to the API should look something like this:

```
 HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get(host + "?" + query)
                    .header("Host", hostReference)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+insert access token here)
                    .asString();
```

So my question is basically which method would be best practice for me to get the access token in runtime and call the API. I can perform this by storing the accesstoken in a static variable but this is not a good solution. What would be best practice in this case?

Comment: Store it in the http session if your application is not stateless - given you’re using MVC I assume it isn’t. You cannot use a static variable unless your entire application only has a single user!

Comment: Ah - I see you’ve already set it in the security context. Just get it from there; it’s already stored in the session.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for your answer! If i use the SecurityContextHolder i can recieve the principal and the credentials among other things but cant seem to get the access token. How can i get it from the session? I have googled this but cant seem to find an example.

Comment: Get the `Authentication` and cast it to a `TokenAuthentication`.

Comment: Actually you already stored into SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenAuth). You can use (TokenAuthentication)Securitycontextholder.getcontext().getauthentication() any where in spring boot to get back the token do whatever you want

Comment: So, something like this would be valid?                                                                   HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get(host + "?" + query)
                    .header("Host", Reference)
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+(TokenAuthentication)Securitycontextholder.getcontext().getauthentication())
                    .asString();